# wp_login_form authentication problems

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello stackoverflow community,
I need help solving my problem with WordPress login authentication. So I've installed CAPATCHA by Best... And in order to put capatcha into custom wp_login_form I've needed to add validation. So I've created this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_authenticate_user', 'my_custom_authenticate', 10, 3 );
function my_custom_authenticate( $user, $username, $password ){
    //Get POSTED value
    if ( ( function_exists( 'cptch_check_custom_form' ) && cptch_check_custom_form() !== true ) || ( function_exists( 'cptchpr_check_custom_form' ) && cptchpr_check_custom_form() !== true ) ) { 
      remove_action('authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20);
      $user = new WP_Error( 'denied', __("<strong>ERROR</strong>: You're CAPTCHA field was wrong.") );
    }
    return $user;
}
```

But it always returns as error. I've added capatcha field with this:

```
add_filter( 'login_form_middle','cptch_custom_form' );
```

Have you ever had this problem, how can I've solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve your problem, but I can recommend this plugin. Set up was simple for the standard login page, it might be worth a look - https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-recaptcha/

Comment: Should perhaps cptch_check_custom_form be cptch_custom_form in your if-statement?

Comment: @danjah still nothing... :/

Comment: Check each single statement in the if to understand which of them is returning the wrong value. Use `var_dump()` to print its current value and see if it is the expected one. There are four chekcs in the `if`: one of those is incorrect and you need to understand which is.

Comment: @Aerendir should i enable debugger in order to see var dump?

Comment: No, you don't need to enable nothing. It's a built-in function. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceed with a "try and fail" approach.

Use `var_dump()` to check the values of each single condition in your `if` statement.

Something like this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_authenticate_user', 'my_custom_authenticate', 10, 3 );
function my_custom_authenticate( $user, $username, $password ){

    /** THIS IS THE DEBUGGING PART */
    var_dump(function_exists( 'cptch_check_custom_form' ));
    var_dump(cptch_check_custom_form()));
    var_dump(function_exists( 'cptchpr_check_custom_form' ));
    var_dump(cptchpr_check_custom_form() !== true);
    /** END DEBUGGING PART */

    //Get POSTED value
    if (
        ( function_exists( 'cptch_check_custom_form' ) && true !== cptch_check_custom_form() )
        || ( function_exists( 'cptchpr_check_custom_form' ) && true !== cptchpr_check_custom_form() ) )
    { 
      remove_action('authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20);
      $user = new WP_Error( 'denied', __("<strong>ERROR</strong>: You're CAPTCHA field was wrong.") );
    }
    return $user;
}
```

NOTE: I've changed the conditions using the [Yoda's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) that is more secure to use.